# Merge and sum two different data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I've 2 different data.tables. I need to merge and sum based on a row values. The examples of two tables are given as Input below and expected output shown below.

**Input**

**Table 1**

```
X   A   B
A   3   
B   4   6
C   5   
D   9   12
```

**Table 2**

```
X   A   B    
A   1   5
B   6   8
C   7   14
D   5   
E   1   1
F   2   3
G   5   6
```

**Expected Output:**

```
X   A   B
A   4   5
B   10  14
C   12  14
D   14  12
E   1   1
F   2   3
G   5   6
```

Comment: You have two data.tables or data.frames? Also, if you have just empty strings there, your columns aren't of numeric type.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this by `rbind`ing the two tables and then do a group by `sum`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = X]
#   X  A  B
#1: A  4  5
#2: B 10 14
#3: C 12 14
#4: D 14 12
#5: E  1  1
#6: F  2  3
#7: G  5  6
```

---

Or using a similar approach with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
    group_by(X) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Note: Here, we assume that the blanks are NA and the 'A' and 'B' columns are `numeric/integer` class

Comment: because of `rbind` instead of `merge` :)

Answer (score 0):

Merge your tables together first, then do the sum. If you later want to drop the individual values you can do so easily.

```
out <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="X", by.y="X", all.x=T, all.y=T)
out$sum <- rowSums(out[2:3])
out$A <- out$B <- NULL  # drop original values
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to do required job for all numeric columns at once

```
library(dplyr)
Table = Table1 %>% full_join(Table2) %>% 
  group_by(X) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(.,na.rm = T)))
```